# How to make this jQuery function in to .click()

Tags: jquery

I don't get it, What I want to do is not when its loading do the typing, but when I click on a link it starts typing. How does this work?

```js
var text = "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
var charCount = text.length;
var currentLetterCount = 0;
var speed = 100; // How fast should it type?
var $input = $(".some-textbox");

function writeLetter() {
    var currentText = $input.val();
    var currentLetter = text.charAt(currentLetterCount);
    currentLetterCount++;
    $input.val(currentText + currentLetter);
    if(currentLetterCount == charCount)
        clearInterval(timerId);
}

var timerId = setInterval(writeLetter, speed);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" style="width: 500px" class="some-textbox" />
```

and jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7K3UE/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to start the timer in a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler instead of directly in the `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(".some-link").click(function() {
  timerId = setInterval(writeLetter, speed);
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7K3UE/13/).

Comment: Perfect,  how can i make it so, when I click on a link with a class of clear it clears the box?

Comment: @omnix - like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7K3UE/14/ Adjust as needed, this prevents multiple timers, resets the typewrite on clear, etc...just remove any behavior you *don't* want, but this has all the bells and whistles.

Comment: Thank you man! I can't wait to become as good as you with javaScript and jQuery, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the trigger into an onclick event or similar:

```
function startTyping() {
var timerId = setInterval(writeLetter, speed);
}

<input type="button" value="Start Animation" onclick="startTyping();">A Link</a>
```

Is that close to what you are after?

Comment: Is there a way where it doesn't involve being in the HTML?

Comment: A rough way around - you may be able to improve on it
$(document).click(function (event) {                    
    var timerId = setInterval(writeLetter, speed);
});

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ( read about | look up | search for ) the `onclick` event; because you're using jQuery, you ought to look at the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

Comment: I know i'm trying to learn how would I make this happen without it being in the HTML. So I can call it in <script> tags

Answer (score 1):

Update your code on this URL http://jsfiddle.net/7K3UE/12/

Added this:

```
$("#lnkClick").bind("click",function(){
    var timerId = setInterval(writeLetter, speed);
})
```

Comment: Like Michael - You're creating a local variable `timerId` (scoped to the `click` handler), not updating a `timerId` which the `writeLetter` function can see/clear - so you're creating a new, never-ending interval with each click.

Comment: Exactly what I want! Is there a way where you can click on another link ...a link with a class of "clear" so it clears the text box? you got the answer!  thanks.

Comment: @omnix - yes, it is indeed wrong, this won't clear the interval when it's finished, see my answer/demo of doing this properly.